# Parse error on Assignment operator

Tags: php, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

I'm new in PHP, so may be I'm wrong *(so don't down-vote me)* because I'm here for learning.

I'm trying to understand Parse error on Assignment operator.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$additon = 2 + 4;
echo "Perform addition: 2 + 4 = " $addition;
?>
```

Why do I get this error?

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected '$addition' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'

And, why the sum of `6` not showing?

Comment: you have forgotten the string concatenation in the echo statement

Comment: Thanks, but still `Undefined variable` error showing and the result not showing.

Comment: You have spelled `addition` wrong in  one instance, that is why the undefined variable.

Comment: at the time of declaration you forgot the `i`  after `o` in the spelling `additon` check taht once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to concatenate these two using a dot.

```
$addition = 2 + 4;
echo "Perform addition: 2 + 4 = ". $addition;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but `Undefined variable` showing and the result not showing.

Comment: Please check your variables. You have declared additon on top instead of addition. :)

Comment: Thanks, works. But why use `concatenate` ?

Comment: That's because "Perform addition: 2 + 4 = " is a string and $addition is a variable. When you're printing these two, they need to be concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

> With concatenation, the period operator has a higher precedence than both the addition and ternary operators, and so parentheses must be used for the correct behaviour.

```
<?php
  echo 'Sum: ' . (1 + 2);
?>
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Hope it helps to understand about concatenation.